# LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemeconfposter.sty' not found

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I am very new to using Beamer to make posters. I am trying to use the confposter theme but even though beamerthemeconfposter.sty is in the same directory as the tex file I am using to generate the poster. Is there any way to resolve this? Here are the beginning lines of my tex file so far:

```
\documentclass[final,unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=91.44,height=121.92,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}
\usepackage{amsmath, fixltx2e}

\bibliographystyle{science}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalsize}
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.} \makeatother

\graphicspath{{C:/path/}}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} 
% Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10}
% Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
```

Comment: Maybe the `.sty` file was saved as `.sty.txt` or something by mistake and Windows does not show the `.txt` extension?

Comment: Yes this is what happened. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will preface this by saying that I, too, am new to the Beamer class, but I may have an answer. I tried `\usetheme{confposter}` and also received the error message that `beamerthemeconfposter.sty` was not found. But then I downloaded the file from http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/08/latex-poster-template/ and was able to compile without issue. Are you certain that `beamerthemeconfposter.sty` is in the same directory as your file?